# GeoPandas overlaps sjoin fails when two geometries are identical

Tags: geopandas, shapely, geos

I am trying to find all polygons that overlap in a collection.
In my unit test I added the following:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import box

s1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0.5]
s2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 0.5]
s3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0.3]
# s3 = [1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 0.3] # Works
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [s1, s2, s3], columns=["e_1", "n_1", "e_2", "n_2", "value"]
)
crs = "+proj=longlat +a=1000000 +b=1000000 +no_defs"
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df,
    crs=crs,
    geometry=[
        box(e_1, n_1, e_2, n_2)
        for _, e_1, n_1, e_2, n_2 in df[
            ["e_1", "n_1", "e_2", "n_2"]
        ].itertuples()
    ],
)
joined = gpd.sjoin(gdf.copy(),
                   gdf,
                   how='inner', op='overlaps')
joined.shape
```

which gives `(0, 12)` meaning it did not join.

If I uncomment the s3 line with 1.1, 2.1 etc. I get the expected result `(2,12)`.

Have I misunderstood how the overlap predicate works or is this a bug?

Comment: If's been a while since I last reviewed thepaper, but I believe the Clementini definition of "overlap"  includes a requirement for a part which is *not* overlapping, so not a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/21577/vince) said in the comments, the behavior of the function is consistent with [the definition of `overlap`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.overlaps.html) (emphasis mine):

> Geometries overlaps if they have more than one **but not all** points in
> common, have the same dimension, and the intersection of the interiors
> of the geometries has the same dimension as the geometries themselves.

The possible values for [`sjoin`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin.html)'s `predicate` argument (formerly named `op`) are: `['covers', 'within', 'contains', 'crosses', None, 'intersects', 'touches', 'covered_by', 'contains_properly', 'overlaps']`.

Their definitions are copied below:

- [overlaps](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.overlaps.html): Geometries overlaps if they have more than one but not all points in common, have the same dimension, and the intersection of the interiors of the geometries has the same dimension as the geometries themselves.
- [covered_by](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.covered_by.html): An object A is said to cover another object B if no points of B lie in the exterior of A.
- [touches](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.touches.html): An object is said to touch other if it has at least one point in common with other and its interior does not intersect with any part of the other. Overlapping features therefore do not touch.
- [intersects](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.intersects.html): An object is said to intersect other if its boundary and interior intersects in any way with those of the other.
- [crosses](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.crosses.html): An object is said to cross other if its interior intersects the interior of the other but does not contain it, and the dimension of the intersection is less than the dimension of the one or the other.
- [contains](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.contains.html): An object is said to contain other if at least one point of other lies in the interior and no points of other lie in the exterior of the object. (Therefore, any given polygon does not contain its own boundary – there is not any point that lies in the interior.) If either object is empty, this operation returns False. This is the inverse of within() in the sense that the expression a.contains(b) == b.within(a) always evaluates to True.
- [within](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.within.html): An object is said to be within other if at least one of its points is located in the interior and no points are located in the exterior of the other. If either object is empty, this operation returns False. This is the inverse of contains() in the sense that the expression a.within(b) == b.contains(a) always evaluates to True.
- [covers](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.covers.html): An object A is said to cover another object B if no points of B lie in the exterior of A. If either object is empty, this operation returns False.
- [contains_properly](https://pygeos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/predicates.html#pygeos.predicates.contains_properly): Returns True if geometry B is completely inside geometry A, with no common boundary points. A contains B properly if B intersects the interior of A but not the boundary (or exterior). This means that a geometry A does not “contain properly” itself, which contrasts with the contains function, where common points on the boundary are allowed.
  I wasn't able to find more details about the `contains_properly` predicate.